# Google Webmaster Tools wrong content keywords

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Google Webmaster Tools shows **views** as the #1 content keyword for my website. This is because I show the number of views each article has on a listings page.
**Views** is not relevant to anything I have on on the website.

Is this keyword important from a SEO perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords listed under **Optimization > Content Keywords** are there on the basis of prevalence and so, as you rightly say, bits of boilerplate text that appear throughout your content will show up high on the list. One of my sites has a forum, so words like "post" and "location" are prevalent.

These words aren't important from an SEO perspective, either to you or to the search engine. Hopefully, at least a few terms relevant to your site's topic are on that list, in which case there's no problem: if not, you *might* have cause for concern, and that warrants a question of its own.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the relevancy of keywords that are important for you under a business perspective by means of search engine optimization and onpage optimization. Your site will always rank for various keywords - relevant or not.

What you probably see here are impressions. Your page or pages are listed in the search result for the keyword "views" but not necessarily clicked and visited. See the columns impressions and clicks and the absolute numbers.

With no further (analytics) data available this could mean you don't rank well for your intended keywords and even got no impressions.

If your Google Webmasteraccount is not that old maybe you just give it some more time to fetch more data.